# Cross reference workaround in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, cross-reference

I have two classes and they have fields of each other types. Now I want to inherit from these classes in parallel *with some magic* so that derived classes could have the same fields but in relative types to each other after inheritance.

```
class Leader {
   public Follower slave;
}

class Follower {
   public Leader master;
}

class Teacher : Leader {}
class Student : Follower {}

class Officer : Leader {}
class Soldier : Follower {}

Teacher.slave.GetType(); // Returns Student
Officer.slave.GetType(); // Returns Soldier

Student.master.GetType(); // Returns Teacher
Soldier.master.GetType(); // Returns Officer
```

Is there a pattern or any solution to get this implemented in C#?

Comment: This sounds like you want "Multiple Inheritance" which is not available in C#. You can inherit more than 1 interface, but only ever 1 class. I am not sure what else you might want to explore as a solution.

Comment: I don´t understand your question. If you put an instance of `Student` to the `slave`-property of your `Teacher`-instance, `teacher.slave.GetType()` will surely return `Student`. However as you didn´t provide how you fill `slave`, we can only guess.

Comment: Apart from what I´ve mentioned before with our current setting it´s possible to have an `Officer` that has a `Student` as a `slave`. Thus you should definitly go for generics as proposed by Zdravko.

Comment: This smells like [the XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to *do* that made you come up with this design?

Comment: It is a fundamental limitation in a statically type-checked language like C#.  The compiler cannot know for a fact that the slave field might actually have a reference to a Student.  Or for that matter any other class that derives from Follower.  Unless you declared Follower `sealed`, you don't want to do that.  A dynamic language like Javascript, Python, VB.NET does not have that problem, it blatantly assumes that the programmer is always smart enough.  C# can also be dynamic when you want it to be, use `dynamic slave;`  Beware the consequences.

Comment: This is somewhat similar to your previous question. It's a like a problem in search of a solution in search of a problem. In any scenario where you need classes with these relationships you can just declare the classes that you need.

Answer (score 1):

you can use generics:

```
class Leader<TFollower> 
{
    public TFollower Slave;
}

class Follower<TLeader>
{
    public TLeader Master; 
}

class Teacher : Leader<Student>
{
}

class Student : Follower<Teacher>
{
}

class Officer : Leader<Soldier>
{
}

class Soldier : Follower<Officer>
{
}
```

Comment: In this case I will need "where" constraint and it ruins everything. I tried. How would you add a method to Leader class, say, "protected void AskFollower(){slave.SetMaster(this);}"

Comment: @user1537809 you'll have to be more specific than "it ruins everything"

Comment: We will face cross reference problem in this case. Just try to call any method of Follower inside Leader.